# The process of removing duplicates taking too long

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, twitter, nlp

I have a very large csv file having around 70,000 tweets containing duplicate vales that i have to remove. The file has three columns (ID, Creation_Date, Text).

An example of the csv file is given below:

```
       ID                          Date                                  Text
"745828866334269441"     "Thu Jun 23 04:05:33 +0000 2017"              "Any TEXT"
"745828863334269434"     "Thu Jun 23 04:06:33 +0000 2017"              "Any TEXT"
"745828343334269425"     "Thu Jun 23 04:07:33 +0000 2017"              "Any TEXT"  
      ................ and so on
```

I am using sequenceMatcher from Difflib in Python. The script is working perfectly fine. The script is listed below:

```
import csv
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

csvInputFile=open('inputFileWithDups.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8", newline='') # Input file name with duplicates
csvOutputFile=open('outputFileWithoutDups.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') # Output file name without duplicates

csvReader = csv.reader(csvInputFile)
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvOutputFile, delimiter=',',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
cleanData = set() # an empty set that will be used to compare and then store the clean tweets without duplicates

for row in csvReader: # reading the inputfile 
   add=True 
   a=row[2] # our third csv column with tweets text that we have to compare for duplicates
   for cleantweet in cleanData:# reading the cleanData set to compare tweet texts.
        f= SequenceMatcher(None,cleantweet,a).ratio() #cleantweet vs row[2] which is text  
        if f > 0.73:
            print(f)
            add=False

   if add: # This will add all the tweets that have a similarty lower than 0.73 (here 1.0 means a 100 percent similarity)
       cleanData.add(row[2])
       csvWriter.writerow(row) # adding all the tweets without duplicates into the new csv file.
csvOutputFile.close()
csvInputFile.close()
```

but a PC having only 4GB of Ram is taking too much time to process. For exmaple: a file having only 5000 tweets took almost 7 hours to process. The next file i have to compare contains 50,000 tweets which means may b 3 days of work :(
I will really appreciate if someone could help me out to speed up the process.
Thanks

Comment: Why not pull them into a database and let it deal with the problem?

Comment: I have no clue what the sequencematcher does. What is your "cleanup-criteria" ? Some kind of unique tweet-id? Or do you compare tweet-texts and if they match more then 73% you discard them? How does your csv file look - post a few line into your question (edit it, format it as code)? If you do semantik analysis over the tweeds texts, it will take time, its a difficult topic with lots of calculations/ datastore behind it....

Comment: Yes i am comparing text of the tweets (column 2) based on a threshold (0.73, 1 for 100 percent similarity) and if a tweets has a threshold higher than 0.73, its a duplicate and and must be removed and the other tweets are written into clean-data set.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Yes advised by my supervisor has well and will do it later since there are too many files to put into a database and that will take time. but for the time being, i have to find a solution for this one.

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux system, you can remove duplicate lines from a text file with this command :

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' duplicate.csv > uniqlines.csv
```

Worked with a 3,700,000 lines file, and took 49 seconds.
My PC is 16Go RAM but it didn't go up to 4.3Go usage, starting operation at 4.1Go.

Comment: Actually i have to remove the duplicates based on a certain similarly percentage (as seen in the code i provided). So i can only use the code mentioned above. For example:

Comment: Following code works in a similar way as ur example:                                                                                                                                                            for row in csvReader:
    #print(row[2])
    if row[2] in cleanData or re.sub('^RT @.*: ', '', row[2]) in cleanData:
        continue
    cleanData.append(row[2])
    csvWriter.writerow(row)                                                                                            This code takes just a few minutes to remove the duplicates. I have to remove partial duplicates as well.